# Regular Expression Search for lowercase or upercase

Tags: regex

I have the following string ttMemberDetail. The string could also be TTMemberDetails. I need a regular expression to match both cases.

Currently my regular expression is (tt\w+) but this obviously doesn't match my uppercase string if I had one. What should my regular expression be?

Comment: Where do you plan to use it?

Comment: You can use `[tT][tT]\w+`

Comment: You can make Regular expressions case insentive by passing a flag e.g. `(?i)(tt\w+)` http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: `/^ttmemberdetail$/i` or `/ttmemberdetail/i`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava this worked!

Comment: Could also do it as `[tT]{2}`

Comment: Where are you using the regex? Can there be `tTMemberDetails`?

Comment: Exclusive upper/lower case is this `(tt|TT)` or `([tT])\1`

Comment: `I need a regular expression to match both cases ( ttMemberDetail  TTMemberDetails)` - I assume you don't have a third and fourth case, so `[tT][tT]` isn't it.

Comment: @sln Why not post that as an answer? Go ahead.

Comment: You can also try : (ttMemberDetail|TTMemberDetails)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - It's unknown if the OP meant a mix of, or exclusive cases. Feel free to post your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the engine or environment the solution can be different. It also depends whether you also want to match `TtMemberDetail` or `tTMemberDetail`.

The easiest is to pass a case insensitive flag with the regex:  `/tt\w+/i` or `(?i)tt\w+`.

In HTML5 pattern attribute value, or in ASP.NET, when you pass a pattern to the client side, you cannot use any modifiers. You can only use character classes to work around that: `[tT][tT]\w+` or `[tT]{2}\w+`.

If you do not want to allow `tTMemberDetail`, but only `tt` or `TT`, you can use alternation, like `(tt|TT)\w+` or a capturing group with a backreference - `([tT])\1\w+`.